# Scroll to element ID inside list

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list with a bunch of items. If there is a certain amount of items the list becomes a scrollbar and if the user clicks a button to see an item which for example is at the bottom of the list, it should automatically scroll to that element. I created a scroll function but it doesn't seem to work correctly.

the javascript looks like this:

```
$('a').on('click', function(e){
    var id = $(e.currentTarget).attr('id')              // catch the ID of the clicked item
    $('#left').animate({                                // #left is the container of the list
       scrollTop: $('#left ul li#'+id+'').offset().top  // scroll to the element which metches the cliced ID
    }, 500);
})
```

I created a simple [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/nnj91Lho/) - Could someone help me out?

Thanks alot!

Comment: @laaposto If you click for example on item2 -> then on item 10 -> then on 7... the behaviour is strange

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are using `.offset().top` that calculate the offset relative to the window but not to the container.

The solution is to use `.offsetTop`

**note**: I really don't know where the extra 8 pixels come from but it works..

```js
$('a').on('click', function(e){
  var id = $(this).attr('id')
  $('#left').animate({
    scrollTop: $('#left ul li#'+id+'')[0].offsetTop - 8
  }, 500);
})
```

```css
#con {


}

#right {
  float: right;
}

#right a {
  display: block;
}

#left {
  float: left;
  height: 500px;
  overflow: scroll
}

#left ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin-top:20px;
}

#left ul li {
}

#left ul li div {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="con">
  <div id="left">
    <ul>
      <li id="1">
        <div>
          Item 1
        </div>
      </li>
      <li id="2">
        <div>
          Item 2
        </div>
      </li>
      <li id="3">
        <div>
          Item 3
        </div>
      </li>
      <li id="4">
        <div>
          Item 4
        </div>
      </li>
      <li id="5">
        <div>
          Item 5
        </div>
      </li>
      <li id="6">
        <div>
          Item 6
        </div>
      </li>
      <li id="7">
        <div>
          Item 7
        </div>
      </li>
      <li id="8">
        <div>
          Item 8
        </div>
      </li>
      <li id="9">
        <div>
          Item 9
        </div>
      </li>
      <li id="10">
        <div>
          Item 10
        </div>
      </li>
      <li id="11">
        <div>
          Item 11
        </div>
      </li>
      <li id="12">
        <div>
          Item 12
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="right">
    <a href="#" id="1">Item1</a>
    <a href="#" id="2">Item2</a>
    <a href="#" id="3">Item3</a>
    <a href="#" id="4">Item4</a>
    <a href="#" id="5">Item5</a>
    <a href="#" id="6">Item6</a>
    <a href="#" id="7">Item7</a>
    <a href="#" id="8">Item8</a>
    <a href="#" id="9">Item9</a>
    <a href="#" id="10">Item10</a>
    <a href="#" id="11">Item11</a>
    <a href="#" id="12">Item12</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/znwjvtzg/

Comment: This is awesome!! Thanks! :-) Question though: Why the `[0]`?

Comment: My Pleasure :) The `[0]` return the **DOM** element (not the jQuery one) so you can use `offsetTop`. You can't use `offsetTop` on a jQuery element. Please accept this answer so it will help to other people.